# ICECAST+Windows 10+SSL

Tags: windows, ssl, icecast

Порты 80 и 443 открыты в маршрутизаторе и со стороны провайдера
Настроил ICECAST 2.4.4. для того что бы он получал Relay из SHOUTcast (это работает), по HTTP все работает как надо. Нужно что бы все работало по HTTPS, для этого установил certbot, с помощью него выполнил запрос SSL сертификата, успешно его получил, через type выполнил объединение fullchain.pem и privkey.pem, после указал путь к файлу в конфигурации ICECAST но при переходе по HTTPS ссылке выдает:

*Этот сайт не может обеспечить безопасное соединение
На сайте ***** используется неподдерживаемый протокол.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
Неподдерживаемый протокол
Клиент и сервер поддерживают разные версии протокола SSL или набора шифров*

Для теста установил IIS, конвертировал сертификат в *.pfx, загрузил его в IIS, добавил сайт и указал этот сертификат, по HTTPS все работает и открывается.